# Can action and quality mean the same?

Tags: definition

Action (verb) is not quality (adjective). But why is the definition of adjective “broken” verb “violently separated into parts”? Isn’t it proper to say adjective “broken” means “in a state of being violently separated into parts”? It’s still strange though because state is not quality.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/broken

Comment: _Broken_ doesn't mean 'being separated into parts', but '_having been_ separated into parts'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting A past participle doesn’t mean action anymore? Or mean action and state at the same time?

Comment: "I have broken (pp) the glass" - I did something to cause damage to it. "The glass is broken (adj) - it is in a state of having been broken.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I mean it has been broken so it’s now broken if it hasn’t been broken it’s not broken.

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to say (and it should be _it has been broken,_ not _have_, and _hasn't_ not _haven't_).

Comment: @Kate Bunting I mean the glass was broken(v) by someone so we can say the glass is broken(adj) if the glass wasn’t broken by someone we can’t say the glass is broken. I mean even though a participle means a state action needs to have been happened.

Comment: Yes, we can. A glass bottle that has cracked, for instance after being left out of doors in very cold weather, is broken even though nobody deliberately broke it.

Comment: @Kate Bunting I mean there should be action “crack.” Unless action didn’t happen we can’t use adjective “broken.”

Comment: But "broken" doesn't mean "broken *by a person who did an action*".  Yes, some change of state had to happen at some time, but *broken* just means "had a change of state at some point".  I think you are over-thinking this.

Comment: @stangdon But why are conjoined twins called “conjoined twins” even though there was no real action that conjoined twins? Conjoined twins have separated not have connected.

Comment: You can take our word for it as native speakers that we _can_ say 'a broken bottle' regardless of who or what may have caused it to be in that state. And conjoined twins have _failed_ to separate in the womb.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Yes that’s what I’m saying they have failed to separate but why not separated twins but connected twins.

Comment: They are born conjoined but usually separated later, silly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the verb **break**, there are three forms: break (infinitive), broke (simple past) and broken (past participle).

For the majority of verbs- the ones where the simple past ends in **-ed**, the simple past is the same as the past participle. This is true for **separate**, which has forms separate (infinitive), separated (simple past) and separated (past participle).

> BROKEN: violently separated into parts

In this definition, separated is a past participle, which is a kind of adjective that is used to describe the state that something is in.

Comment: I think it’s off-topic, but “state” and “quality” can be a synonym each other?

Comment: Or an adjective can describe state, not only quality?

Comment: A quality (a characteristic or feature of someone or something) is generally permanent. A state (a condition or way of being that exists at a particular time )describes the quality of something at a particular time. You can often use the same adjective to describe the state or quality of something.

Comment: @Iloveeverybody I recommend waiting a day or two before accepting an answer. Other people are more likely to provide (maybe better) alternative answers if you don't accept the first answer straight away.

Comment: It is also quite possible to very **gently** break things, as I can attest from attempts to repair a semi-functioning watch! No violence is required. This also applies to breaking/broken hearts!

Comment: @RonaldSole you are absolutely right.  The OP's extract from M-W is definition 1. Definition 2b from the same source (not working properly) covers your watch.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about action vs quality, but about the *tense* of the verb, that is, it's relationship to time.

If we say something "is broken", we are using a *past* participle as an adjective, so are saying that the verb "to break" applies to something that has already happened. Some previous event happened that means it is no longer in one piece, so now it is “violently separated into parts”.

If we instead say something "is breaking", we are using a *present* participle as an adjective, so are saying that the verb "to break" applies to what is happening to it right now. So that would be “in a state of being violently separated into parts”.

> The blast threw him out of the breaking window. Afterwards, he looked back at the broken window.